# The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting

Tags: python, django

```
import os

# Строим пути внутри проекта, используя os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

# Настройки быстрого старта разработки - не подходят для продакшена
# См. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ваш_секретный_ключ_здесь'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Определение приложений
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'

# База данных
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Проверка пароля
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Локализация
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Статические файлы (CSS, JavaScript, изображения)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

# Тип поля по умолчанию для первичного ключа
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Настройки электронной почты
# (Вы можете настроить их собственными SMTP-настройками)
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

# Локальные настройки (необязательно)
try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Вам прямым текстом написано что STATICFILES_DIRS не должен включать в себя STATIC_ROOT, по умолчанию он вроде как равносилен `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` оттуда и проблема, задайте другую директорию вместо static для STATICFILES_DIRS, можете даже сохранять их внутри папки static:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "my_folder"),
]
```

Только насколько мне известно, папка указанная для STATICFILES_DIRS не создается автоматически